# Reading from text url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program in JavaScript, that I already had in Java. I've tried a few different ways reading a **url.txt** file, and I can't say that I understand any of it. So I would like to avoid Jquery and other non standard options, because I'm trying to learn this language. Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getText()">Try It</button>
    <p id="text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function getText() {
    var bool = true;
    var xReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
    xReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
    xReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
    xReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);
    xReq.open(
      "GET",
      "http://jeff.cis.cabrillo.edu/datasets/santa-cruz-addresses.txt");
    xReq.send();
}
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100;
    } else {
        // Unable to compute progress information  total size is unknown
    }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "The transfer is complete.";
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "An error occurred";
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "canceled by the user.";
}
```

Eventually I will split the txt file up into lines, and into arrays, but first I need to figure this out , any help would be awesome thanks.

Comment: What exactly is it are you trying to do? if you could elaborate on your query it would be great.

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @damagedCoda I don't know what query is, and I thought I was clear?

Comment: @damagedCoda well if ur actually interested, the look here https://github.com/whoscoffee/SantaCruzLoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because security reasons you cannot make javascript request to external domain. This is possible only if external allow to do that by adding this header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

For your issue the best will be just use ajax to read static file from local.

Answer (score 1):

The `http://jeff.cis.cabrillo.edu` should support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

That is, it should tell the browser, through it's response headers, that it has no problem it's services are accessed by this request.

If this information is not found in the response, the browser will simply generate an error.

Comment: oh I see, that's weird, well he is my old teacher who I can talk to. But any alternatives? I can download the txt and use it locally.... buttt idk, can I use java to Scan the url and sent it to my script somehow?? Oh and why would java be able to scan and JavaScript cannot?